# Subscribing to part of an ngrx Store only

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx-store

I've been having a great deal of trouble getting a component in my Ionic/Angular application to subscribe to **part** of an @ngrx store.

In my app I have an index.ts file containing:

```js
import * as fromReducer1 from './reducer1';
import * as fromReducer2 from './reducer2';

export interface ApplicationState {
  reducer1: fromReducer1.Reducer1State;
  reducer2: fromReducer2.Reducer2State;
}
```

in reducer1 I have:

```js
export interface Reducer1State {
  products {
   items: any[],
   prices: any[]
  },
  filters: any[]
}
```

and an export function

```js
export function Reducer1 etc
```

In my component I can happily subscribe to Reducer 1 by doing this:

```js
this.store.select('Reducer1')
      .subscribe((store: any) => {})
```

This works ok but what I want to do is make my component subscribe to Reducer1 but **ONLY** pick up changes to the Products object i.e if the filters object changes then I am not interested in it.  Either that or at least when the component subscribes it can detect whether the products object was identical to the last time i.e using `DistinctUntilChanged` (I could not get that to work though)

How do I do that (I've searched and tried several things but have not managed to get anything to work).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write inner selector

```
// take the whole state reducer
export const reducer2State= (state: State) => state.transactions;
//take inner reducer 
export const getInnerState = createSelector(reducer2State, 
        fromReducer2.something);
// select in component
this.innerReducer = this.store.select(fromRoot.getInnerState );
```

If you are using ngrx2 checkout out this [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts).
If you are using ngrx4 checkout out this [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app)

Comment: what is the fromRoot bit ?

Comment: fromRoot is your main reducer.

Comment: what ngrx version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.3 - I'm not sure I have a "main" reducer - I just have a bunch of reducers for each store e.g Reducer1, Reducer 2 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154513/discussion-between-alexkhymenko-and-richard-shergold).